# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method

Tags: wildfly

I am getting exception after lookup the ejb and call it's method..I am upgrading jboss4.2.3 to wildfly

see stack trace:---

```
ERROR [org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction] (default task-41) Dispatch[/submitActivityForm] to method 'showDetails' returned an exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:274) [struts-1.0.jar:1.2.7]
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:194) [struts-1.0.jar:1.2.7]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419) [struts-1.0.jar:1.2.7]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224) [struts-1.0.jar:1.2.7]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194) [struts-1.0.jar:1.2.7]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432) [struts-1.0.jar:1.2.7]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at com.tzaconsulting.ptw.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:75) [ptw-common-1.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
```

Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "com.tzaconsulting.ptw.maintenance.ejb.activity.ActivityBusiness.showDetails(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/tzaconsulting/ptw/maintenance/common/po/Activity;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, com/tzaconsulting/ptw/maintenance/web/delegate/ActivityDelegate, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for resolved class, com/tzaconsulting/ptw/maintenance/ejb/activity/ActivityBusiness, have different Class objects for the type ctivityBusiness.showDetails(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/tzaconsulting/ptw/maintenance/common/po/Activity; used in the signature
        at com.tzaconsulting.ptw.maintenance.web.delegate.ActivityDelegate.getCurrentActivity(ActivityDelegate.java:240) [classes:]
        at com.tzaconsulting.ptw.maintenance.web.action.ActivityDispatchAction.showDetails(ActivityDispatchAction.java:626) [classes:]
    ... 43 more

Answer (score 0):

I've also done a migration from 4.2.2 to wildly and the containers behave differently.

In 4 you have unified classloading wich means that there is only one classloader for everything. Sounds you can load every class from anywhere. Wildly has a different classloader for each app so that you will get linkage errors.

The solution is to set dependencies between the different apps and you should be fine.

Btw.: depending on your project layout, it could result in a larger refactoring.